# How we can write a data in to text file using wso2esb

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

i am getting a data or string from front end i am setting the data or string in one property
that property data i need to send in text file every time they will send the data i need keep the data in same file  without override how can i do i have done using VFS transport i uncommented sender section of vfs in configuration file even though its not working fine below configuration

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
           name="FileWrite"
           transports="https http"
           startOnLoad="true"
           trace="disable">
       <description/>
       <target>
          <inSequence>
             <property name="error" expression="//error/text()" scope="default"/>
             <log level="full"/>
          </inSequence>
          <outSequence>
             <log>
 <property name="error" expression="get-property('error')" scope="default"/>
                <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
             </log>
             <payloadFactory>
                <format>
                   <error>$1</error>
                </format>
                <args>
                   <arg expression="get-property('error')"/>
                </args>
             </payloadFactory>
             <log level="full"/>
             <send>
                <endpoint>
                   <address uri="vfs:file:///home/youtility2/Desktop/Errorlog.text"/>
                </endpoint>
             </send>
             <log level="full"/>
          </outSequence>
       </target>
       <parameter name="transport.vfs.Append">true</parameter>
    </proxy>
```

i created text file on desktop but data is not writing in text file and also not giving any exception also will refer something for this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15765141/can-we-append-the-data-in-single-text-file-using-wso2esb/15769531#15769531 i got this but in that they are moving text files but i wish to append the data in to single file

Answer (score 2):

You have to enable VFS Transport for the Proxy service. In proxy creation/edit wizard you can select necessary transports. Once you have enabled VFS transport in axis2.xml, VFS will apear as an available transport for services. So if it is to use in a proxy service it should be enabled to that particular service as well.

So in your proxy element, transport attribute will be transports="https http vfs"

In order to append to the same file, define the transport.vfs.Append parameter with the file URI as described in the doc[2]

[2]http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB450/VFS+Transport

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
           name="FileWrite"
           transports="https http vfs"
           startOnLoad="true"
           trace="disable">
       <description/>
       <target>
          <inSequence>
             <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
             <property name="error" expression="//error/text()" scope="default"/>
             <log level="full"/>
          </inSequence>
          <outSequence>
             <log>
 <property name="error" expression="get-property('error')" scope="default"/>
                <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
             </log>
             <payloadFactory>
                <format>
                   <error>$1</error>
                </format>
                <args>
                   <arg expression="get-property('error')"/>
                </args>
             </payloadFactory>
             <log level="full"/>
             <send>
                <endpoint>
                   <address uri="vfs:file:///home/youtility2/Desktop/Errorlog.text?transport.vfs.Append=true"/>
                </endpoint>
             </send>
             <log level="full"/>
          </outSequence>
       </target>
       <parameter name="transport.vfs.Append">true</parameter>
    </proxy>
```

Comment: ERROR - Axis2Sender Unexpected error during sending message out
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The VFS transport doesn't support synchronous responses. Please use the appropriate (out only) message exchange pattern. i tried as per ur guidence but its giving error like above

Comment: when ever i am sending data to endpoint i need to test endpoint that time i given my above endpoint but its giving error test endpoint is not success error is  [Test address only supported for HTTP and HTTPS protocols]

Comment: This meaning of this second issue ( [Test address only supported for HTTP and HTTPS protocols]) is Testing feature for endpoints hasn't been implemented for VFS endpoints. We only support Testing for HTTP and HTTPS endpoints.

Comment: Please add <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>  to your inSequence.

Comment: k got u but when ever above send configuration i added in insequence its giving errors same configuration in out sequence not givings error but not working output is not coming

Comment: I edited your proxy config in the question with OUT_ONLY and transport.vfs.Append=true. Please try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Below code shows the capability to insert payload into a file. 
You don't need to use vfs as transport.

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="WriteIntoFile"
       transports="https,http"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <property name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName"
                   expression="fileName.xml')"
                   scope="transport"/>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="vfs:ftp://admin:admin@localhost:21/srcFolder?vfs.passive=true"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
   </target>
</proxy>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to set VFS as a transport in your proxy to use vfs.
2. The way you define transport.vfs.Append parameter is wrong

it should be as 
In URL

```
vfs:file:///home/user/test/out? transport.vfs.Append=true "
```

as Parameter

```
<parameter name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileURI">file:///home/user/test/out? transport.vfs.Append=true </parameter>
```

1. vfs parameters are missing in your configuration.

For vfs service level parameters you can refer [1].

I just roughly edit your proxy try with this.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
           name="FileWrite"
           transports="vfs" statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
       <description/>
       <target>
          <inSequence>
             <property name="error" expression="//error/text()" scope="default"/>
             <log level="full"/>
          </inSequence>
          <outSequence>
             <log>
 <property name="error" expression="get-property('error')" scope="default"/>
                <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
             </log>
             <payloadFactory>
                <format>
                   <error>$1</error>
                </format>
                <args>
                   <arg expression="get-property('error')"/>
                </args>
             </payloadFactory>
             <log level="full"/>
             <send>
                <endpoint>
                   <address uri="vfs:file:///home/youtility2/Desktop/Errorlog? transport.vfs.Append=true"/>
                </endpoint>
             </send>
             <log level="full"/>
          </outSequence>
       </target>
       <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">10</parameter>
       <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">file:///home/youtility2/Desktop/Errorlog.text</parameter>
       <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">.*.xml</parameter>
       <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">text/xml</parameter>
       <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterFailure">MOVE</parameter>
    </proxy>
```

[1].http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/VFS+Transport

Comment: when ever i am sending data to endpoint i need to test endpoint that time i given my above endpoint but its giving error test endpoint is not success error is  [Test address only supported for HTTP and HTTPS protocols]

Comment: you can add transports as follows transports="https,http,vfs" try with it replacing existing trasport entery

Comment: ** i have done  but no result **  but when ever above send configuration i added in insequence its giving errors same configuration in out sequence not giving error but not working output is not coming

Comment: Are you sure whether the gvien xpath is present in your message. Just try with ordinary request.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try **class mediator** in wso2esb.In java class Using FileWriter it is possible to write into text file like this:

```
FileWriter(File file, boolean append)
```

or

```
FileWriter(String fileName, boolean append)
```