# Can we store a string in a text file in wso2esb?

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I have a text file on my local system I wish to append the data in particular file as synchronously.

I have tried many ways, but it's not working.

ESB has this future in Oracle SOA. We can add in FILE ADAPTER. In ESB it's neither giving errors nor expected result.

My configuration is like this:

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="FileWrite" transports="http,vfs" statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
  <target>
     <inSequence>
        <log>
           <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
        </log>
     </inSequence>
     <outSequence>
        <log>
           <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
        </log>
        <payloadFactory>
           <format>
              <error>error404</error>
           </format>
        </payloadFactory>
        <send>
           <endpoint>
              <address uri="vfs:file:///home/youtility2/Desktop/Errorlog"/>
           </endpoint>
        </send>
     </outSequence>
  </target>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileURI">file:///home/user/test/out? transport.vfs.Append=true</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">10</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">Errorlog.text</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">text/xml</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterFailure">MOVE</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName">Errorlog.xml</parameter>
  <description></description>
</proxy>
```

Actually I kept a log mediator in `outSequence`. The `inSequence` mediator is not sending the data in to the `outSequence` process not forwarding into `outSequence`. That's why I think that the above configuration is not working.

Any reference for this?

I tried above configuration in `inSequence` also. It's giving errors like this:

> ERROR - Axis2Sender Unexpected error during sending message out
>   org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: 
>   The VFS transport doesn't support synchronous responses. Please use
>   the appropriate (out only) message exchange pattern

Please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15803063/how-we-can-write-a-data-in-to-text-file-using-wso2esb).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, you are setting a property inside a log mediator which is a predefined property, (ie:`OUT_ONLY`) which is used to indicate the request is only the "out-only" request. So, system, wont expect the response back. That is why, you are not getting anything in your outsequence.
DO NOT USE the predefined properties in the Log mediator,which will cause issues.

Keep some text in the log meditaor to indictae the flow of the message.
eg:

```
  <inSequence>
        <log>
           <property name="INSEQUENCEEEEEEE" value="********"/>
        </log>
     </inSequence>
```

Like wise keep different descriptive log in the outsequence and see whether you are getting the message there, without any issue.