# Using VFS to Write a File

Tags: wso2, esb, vfs

I've recently started working with WSO2 and I am encountering a problem with using the VFS to write to a file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="PX_WriteToFile" transports="https,http,vfs" statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <loopback/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                <format>
                    <Fungus xmlns="">
                        <Info>$1 is a fungus with a $2 cap. It has $3 stem with $4 gills. It may be dangerous having $5</Info>
                    </Fungus>
                </format>
                <args>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//name"/>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//cap"/>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//stem"/>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//gill"/>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//toxin"/>
                </args>
            </payloadFactory>
            <property name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName" value="reply.txt" scope="transport" type="STRING"/>
            <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true" scope="default" type="BOOLEAN"/>
            <send>
                <endpoint>
                    <address uri="vfs:file://C:/vfs/reply"/>
                </endpoint>
            </send>
        </outSequence>
    </target>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">MOVE</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">5</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess">file://C:/vfs/map</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">file://C:/vfs/reply</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterFailure">file://C:/vfs/maf</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">text/xml</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterFailure">MOVE</parameter>
    <description/>
</proxy>
```

When executing this proxy service I get

```
[2015-06-03 16:57:24,377]  WARN {SERVICE_LOGGER.PX_WriteToFile} -  Executing fault handler due to exception encountered
[2015-06-03 16:57:24,378]  WARN {SERVICE_LOGGER.PX_WriteToFile} -  ERROR_CODE : 0 ERROR_MESSAGE : Unexpected error during sending message ou
t
[2015-06-03 16:57:24,379]  INFO {SERVICE_LOGGER.PX_WriteToFile} -  FaultHandler executing impl: org.apache.synapse.mediators.MediatorFaultHa
ndler
[2015-06-03 16:57:24,380]  WARN {SERVICE_LOGGER.PX_WriteToFile} -  Executing fault sequence mediator : fault
[2015-06-03 16:57:24,380]  INFO {SERVICE_LOGGER.PX_WriteToFile} -  To: , From: 136.227.134.115, WSAction: urn:mediate, SOAPAction: urn:media
te, ReplyTo: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, MessageID: http://identifiers.wso2.com/messageid/1433365044366/4616446479, Dire
ction: response, MESSAGE = Executing default 'fault' sequence, ERROR_CODE = 0, ERROR_MESSAGE = Unexpected error during sending message out,
Envelope: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2
005/08/addressing"><s:Header>



</s:Header><s:Body><Fungus><Info>Silvercap is a fungus with a Blue, White and Pearlescent cap. It has No stem with Smooth gills. It may be d
angerous having Mercury comparable to Tuna/lb</Info></Fungus></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

VFS is enabled (both Receiver and Sender)
and I have tried using

[Writing on a text file using VFS in WSO2 ESB 4.8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27856089/writing-on-a-text-file-using-vfs-in-wso2-esb-4-8-1)

as a reference without luck.

Is there something that I have overlooked?

Thank you,

```
Additional Logging with Tracing enabled.
[2015-06-04 08:09:39,784]  INFO {TRACE_LOGGER} -  End : Property mediator
[2015-06-04 08:09:39,784]  INFO {TRACE_LOGGER} -  Start : Send mediator
[2015-06-04 08:09:39,785]  INFO {TRACE_LOGGER} -  Sending message through endpoint : null resolving to address = vfs:file:.=///C:/vfs/reply
[2015-06-04 08:09:39,785]  INFO {TRACE_LOGGER} -  SOAPAction: urn:mediate
[2015-06-04 08:09:39,785]  INFO {TRACE_LOGGER} -  WSA-Action: urn:mediate
[2015-06-04 08:09:39,811]  WARN {TRACE_LOGGER} -  Executing fault handler due to exception encountered
[2015-06-04 08:09:39,811]  WARN {SERVICE_LOGGER.PX_WriteToFile} -  Executing fault handler due to exception encountered
[2015-06-04 08:09:39,811]  WARN {TRACE_LOGGER} -  ERROR_CODE : 0
[2015-06-04 08:09:39,811]  WARN {TRACE_LOGGER} -  ERROR_MESSAGE : Unexpected error during sending message out
[2015-06-04 08:09:39,811]  WARN {TRACE_LOGGER} -  ERROR_DETAIL : org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Unexpected error during sending message out
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.handleException(Axis2Sender.java:172)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendOn(Axis2Sender.java:71)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:309)
    at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint.send(AbstractEndpoint.java:333)
    at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AddressEndpoint.send(AddressEndpoint.java:59)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:97)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:77)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:47)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:131)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:268)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LoopBackMediator.mediate(LoopBackMediator.java:42)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:77)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:47)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:131)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.java:166)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.doPost(CarbonServlet.java:231)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The VFS transport doesn't support synchronous responses. Please use the appropriate (out only) message exchange pattern.
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportSender.sendMessage(VFSTransportSender.java:110)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportSender.invoke(AbstractTransportSender.java:112)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.DynamicAxisOperation$DynamicOperationClient.send(DynamicAxisOperation.java:185)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.DynamicAxisOperation$DynamicOperationClient.executeImpl(DynamicAxisOperation.java:167)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.send(Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.java:482)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendOn(Axis2Sender.java:59)
    ... 48 more

[2015-06-04 08:09:39,811]  WARN {TRACE_LOGGER} -  ERROR_EXCEPTION : org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Unexpected error during sending message out
[2015-06-04 08:09:39,811]  WARN {SERVICE_LOGGER.PX_WriteToFile} -  ERROR_CODE : 0 ERROR_MESSAGE : Unexpected error during sending message out
```

Comment: I've also used 
http://wso2.com/library/articles/2012/01/wso2-esb-example-file-exchanging-hub-part-1/ as a reference.

I should also add that all folders exist.

Comment: Tried it with the vfs:file:///C:/... and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

In your endpoint address, vfs:file:// is the protocol and the rest is the directory that must start with a /

The directory C:\vfs\reply must exist

```
<send>
  <endpoint>
    <address uri="vfs:file:///C:/vfs/reply"/>
  </endpoint>
</send>
```

Comment: Tried it with the vfs:file:///C:/vfs/reply and it doesn't work.

Comment: OUT_ONLY is not a BOOLEAN, but a STRING, look in wso2carbon.log, you should find something like 'The VFS transport doesn't support synchronous responses. Please use the appropriate (out only) message exchange'

Comment: That appears to be the problem.